# Choropleth maps with gray boundaries

Tags: r, choropleth

I'm using R and am trying to create a choropleth map using `GISTools`. My code is like:

```
choropleth(us_state, us_state$smallbiz1998, shades)
plot(us_interstate, add = TRUE)
```

`us_state` is a map of US states and `us_interstate` is a map of the interstate highways.

I want the boundaries of US states to be in gray. How can I do this?

choropleth documentation indicates that you can specify `Additional parameters to be passed on to the plot method for sp.`. However, when I try `choropleth(us_state, us_state$smallbiz1998, shades, col = "gray")` it throws an error.

(If it were changing the interstate highways to be gray, it's easy, just change the second line to `plot(us_interstate, add = TRUE, col = "gray")`).

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to `choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$smallbiz1998, shades, border = "gray")`